# Is it possible to cancel navigation in NavigationStart event?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to cancel the route navigation inside the events function?

```
 this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          if (cancel) event.preventDefault(); // <-- ? or something similar
        }
 });
```

Comment: It is not good to cancel navigation in the `NavigationStart`

Comment: but, it's possible?

Comment: better to do in `CanActivate` or using `CanDeactivate`

Comment: it is possible but may cause unexpected behaviors

Comment: I'm curious. how? because the `event` variable doesn't seems I can affect on it. and I need that solution because I maintain legacy code and I can't change much there. and what are the unexpected behaviors for example?

Comment: One potential issue is that it will prevent remaining handlers from being executed, If you have multiple event handlers bounded, others like blank page or navigational loop, but it all depends on your needs

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to cancel a navigation, you shoud use the [`canActivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateFn) guard and return `false` of an `Observable` returning `false` or redirect to a page by returning a `UrlTree`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this with event reason as well

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    if (cancel) {
      event.cancel = true;
      event.reason = "navigation canceled";
    }
  }
});
```

note: these 2 properties only available in navigationStart event, once started you can not cancel

also important to unsubscribe from the router events afterwards

you can check more here: https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationStart